# Using MGF for multivariate random variables

Tags: distributions, moments

How do you use MGF for solving moment based questions for multivariate random variables?

For the single variable case, we:

find $E(e^{tX})$, find the interval in which it exists (around 0), differentiate it n times and plug in t as 0 to receive the n'th moment $E(X^n)$.

With a general multivariate distribution like $f_{XY}(x,y)$, how do I use MGF to find stuff like $E(X), E(XY), E(Y)$ etc?

I read wikipedia and some other pages but they keep losing me at some point.

I understand the MGF will be  $E(e^{t'X})$ where t and X are now vectors but where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write down what your last expression means in $2$ dimensions:
$$
m(t_1,t_2) =  E[e^{t_1X_1 + t_2 X_2}],
$$
then we get 
$$
\frac{\partial m}{\partial t_i} = E[X_i e^{t_1X_1 + t_2 X_2}]
$$
and we can evaluate at $t_1=t_2 = 0$ to get $E[X_i]$ for $i = 1,2$.
More interesting:
$$
\frac{\partial m^2}{\partial t_1 \partial t_2} = E[X_1 X_2 e^{t_1X_1 + t_2 X_2}]
$$
and again evaluating at $t_1=t_2 = 0$ to get $E[X_1X_2]$ which we need for the covariance.
Play with the derivatives and you should get all mixed moments.

Comment: Shouldn't the derivatives be partial?

Comment: Yes, I did not use the proper "d" but of course partial.